# Custom a tootip by using qtip

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, qtip

I am interesting the tootip by this [example.](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#styles)

My current qtip is for a table cell.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('td[title]').qtip();
});
```

How to modify it to get the same effect as the example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using qtip2 rather than qtip1 will solve the problem.

CSS:

```
.tdStyle{
     background: #123456;
     color: #FEDCBA;
     text-align: left;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: 2px solid white;
     width: 400px;
       };
```

JS:

```
$('td[title]').qtip({
style: {
    classes: 'tdStyle'
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the style object referenced in your example directly to the .qtip() method. If memory serves:

```
$('td[title]').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Neat!'
    },
    style: {
        tip: 'leftMiddle',
        border: {
            width: 10,
            radius: 6,
            color: '#FA6900'
        },
        background: '#F38630',
        color: '#333'
    }
});
```

EDIT: I should also mention that you won't see anything unless you specify content to place inside the tooltip.  This is also typically done in the configuration object passed to qtip.  Updated my example.